# Why is Block Explorer so slow?

Tags: network

Why is the [Block Explorer](http://www.blockexplorer.com) so slow?  It used to work reasonably fast, and now it just spins and spins for 20 minutes?  Is it doing some kind of timing out?

This is a very important utility for the whole Bitcoin network and it is in everyone's better interest that they can look up Bitcoin values without having to have an account somewhere.

Comment: You can use [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) as an alternative

Comment: There are a few other block explorers too, such as [ABE](http://abe.john-edwin-tobey.org/) (which is open source). So I wouldn't say that blockexplorer.com is "a very important utility for the whole bitcoin network". But it's a good tool, sure.

Comment: I`m currently working on an alternative block explorer that will be sitting on Google's mainframe (fast and reliable, can handle basically anything), keep your fingers crossed for awhile longer;).

Comment: that's cool, dude.

Comment: You can use [blockr.io block explorer](http://blockr.io) as an alternative fot Bitcoin and Litecoin

Comment: You can also use https://www.biteasy.com as an alternative. It's pretty fast and includes a nice REST API. Testnet is supported as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On what pages is it slow? It only seems a little slower for me.

The "mirror" (which is actually usually the main server) went down for a while, so BBE switched to my server, which has much fewer resources.

Comment: It is very, very slow on looking at a new address and normal, fast looking for an existing address.